# Riemann sphere and Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Could somebody please clarify the following for me?

I am not too clear about the relationship between the Riemann sphere and Möbius maps. I know that we can through projection make some Möbius maps correspond to isometries of the sphere. But it is not a bijection right? Which maps have corresponding isometries and which don't, vice versa?

Thanks

Comment: Only some Möbius maps give isometries of the sphere. What's really going on is that the Möbius maps are the automorphisms of the Riemann sphere, considered as a one-dimensional complex manifold.

Answer (score 1):

Möbius maps $(az+b)/(cz+d)$ with $ad-bc\ne 0$ are 1-1 onto maps of the Riemann sphere.  You need to add infinity to the plane to get a statement this simple.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that all Möbius maps cannot be isometries : if $M$ is an isometric Möbius map, then $\lambda M$, $\lambda \neq 1$ is also Möbius but certainly cannot be isometric.

Also, the involution $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is an isometry of the Riemann sphere, but it is not Möbius.

Actually, the symmetry group of the sphere is $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$, and the group of Möbius transformation is $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

As it has been pointed out by Chris, the real interest of the Möbius maps is that it is precisely the biholomorphisms of the Riemann sphere.

Comment: While most of what you said here is true, the first paragraph makes little sense, since you can't scale in the Mobius group.

Comment: "you can't scale in the Mobius group" : you won't change a Mobius transformation $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ by replacing it by $\frac{kaz+kb}{kcz+kd}$ but you will obtain a different (and well defined) Mobius transformation with $\frac{kaz+kb}{cz+d}$.

Comment: to put it differently : the Mobius group, seen as a subset of the vector space of holomorphic maps on the riemann sphere, is invariant under scalar multiplication. thus is certainly cannot consist only of isometries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main geometric point is that there is a difference between *conformal maps* (which preserve the angles between tangent vectors) and *isometries* (which also preserve all notions of distance -- and in particular, norms of tangent vectors).

As people have said, the Möbius group tells you what the holomorphic (complex) automorphisms are of the sphere, $S^2 = \mathbb{C} P^1$. But in one complex dimension (i.e., for Riemann surfaces) you can think of orientation-preserving, conformal (i.e., angle-preserving) transformations as the *same thing* as complex transformations.

So the only difference between Möbius transformations and isometries are, really, that (1) the former has to preserve orientation, and (2) the former need not preserve distances -- only angles. This explains why, for instance, scaling is a Möbius transformation, but is not an isometry.